# I get a "Syntax error in INSERT INTO" statement from MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having some trouble with MS Access, I keep getting a syntax error when I try inserting a new record:

[image]

Can anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: `Time` is a reserved word in Access. Enclose it inside square brackets: `[Time]`

Comment: As are Year and Name. Should avoid reserved words in naming convention. Should post code, error messaged, and sample data as formatted text, not images.